# Why does Ansible list a service, but with a status "not-found"?

Tags: ansible, systemd, systemctl

**TL;DR**

What does a service status of `not-found` mean in Ansible's service facts?

**More in detail:**

With Ansible you can list all services on a host along with their states by:

```
ansible -m service_facts myhost
```

Example output:

```json
myhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "services": {
            "ModemManager.service": {
                "name": "ModemManager.service",
                "source": "systemd",
                "state": "running",
                "status": "enabled"
            },
            "NetworkManager-dispatcher.service": {
                "name": "NetworkManager-dispatcher.service",
                "source": "systemd",
                "state": "inactive",
                "status": "enabled"
            },
            ...
            }
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

So far so good, but what about this service:

```json
"systemd-timesyncd.service": {
   "name": "systemd-timesyncd.service",
   "source": "systemd",
   "state": "stopped",
   "status": "not-found"
}
```

What does the status `not-found` mean?

The problem arising is that I have an Ansible playbook which would disable this service. To prevent any error if the service to be stopped does not exist at all, I added a check (see `when` attribute):

```yaml
- name: Populate service facts
  ansible.builtin.service_facts: ~

- name: Disable systemd-timesyncd service (replaced with chrony as NTP server)
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: stopped
    enabled: false
  when: "item in services"
  with_items:
    - systemd-timesyncd.service
  become: true
```

This playbook snippet would throw an error saying "service systemd-timesyncd.service not found". So, I realized that the check is not enough. Instead, I had to replace the following:

```yaml
when: "item in services"
```

with:

```yaml
when: "(item in services) and (services[item].status != 'not-found')"
```

But I would like to understand why this is the case. Why are non-existing services reported (i.e., included in Ansible's "service" facts) although they are reported as `not-found`?

Is this an Ansible "feature"? Or does this strange behavior come from the underlying `systemd`?

Answer (score 0):

> ***Why are non-existing services reported (i.e., included in Ansible's `service_facts`) although they are reported as `not-found`? ... does this ... come from the underlying `systemd`?***

It seems that the Ansible [`service_facts` module – Return service state information as fact data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html) only performs an

```bash
systemctl --full --type service --all
systemctl --full --type service --all | grep not-found
● display-manager.service                                                                   not-found inactive dead    display-manager.service
● sntp.service                                                                              not-found inactive dead    sntp.service
● syslog.service                                                                            not-found inactive dead    syslog.service
● systemd-sysusers.service                                                                  not-found inactive dead    systemd-sysusers.service
● ypbind.service                                                                            not-found inactive dead    ypbind.service
● yppasswdd.service                                                                         not-found inactive dead    yppasswdd.service
● ypserv.service                                                                            not-found inactive dead    ypserv.service
● ypxfrd.service                                                                            not-found inactive dead    ypxfrd.service
```

as one could double check via the minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - service_facts:

  - debug:
      var: (ansible_facts.services).keys() | sort
```

The reported service keys and states are (almost) the same.

If interested in which code exactly is executed or in more depth information and details, just have a look at the source of [`ansible/modules/service_facts.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py), line [#253](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py#L253) and [#281](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py#L281).

**Thanks To**

- [List of available services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501492/266568)

---

> ***What does the status `not-found` mean?***

That seems to be more a question for [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), like in [Cleaning/Debugging services](https://superuser.com/a/1755215/754490)

> *If the unit is `not-found` and `inactive` yet stays in the list, then it's probably `wanted` or `required` by another unit. For example, the unit is probably still `enabled`, i.e. your `/etc/systemd/system/*.target.wants` contains a symlink to it.*

```bash
sudo grep -R 'systemd-timesyncd.service' /etc/systemd/system
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/chronyd.service:Conflicts=ntpd.service systemd-timesyncd.service
```